# The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider 'MSOLAP' for Linked server 'SSAS' does not support the required interface

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am getting this error when I try to update a cube using the linked server:

[image]

> Msg 7390, Level 16, State 2, Line 20 The requested operation could not
>   be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "SSAS"
>   does not support the required transaction interface.

My query:

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(max) = 'UPDATE CUBE [TESTING] SET (
       [Measures].[Group Curr Amt Original],[Local Currency].[Local Currency].&[USD],[Time].[Fis Yr Month SKey].&[201806], [Transaction Currency].CurrencyName].&[US Dollar],  )=1234 USE_EQUAL_ALLOCATION;'

EXEC (@command) at SSAS

DECLARE @command2 VARCHAR(max) = 'commit tran'

EXEC (@command2) at SSAS
```

If I do not commit the transaction the update works. Is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: Please include the errors as text, not images

Answer (score 3):

Please drop and recreate the linked server using the options mentioned [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2790/dynamic-xmla-using-tsql-for-sql-server-analysis-services/).

> Make sure RPC and RPC Out are set to True
>
> Make sure Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions is False

Comment: Greg, It is already set to True. Any other advice would be really helpful.

Comment: @user9833902 how about setting "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions" to false?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using @GregGalloway's answer comment. Here's a easy way to enable this ability for a linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = N'SSAS'
    ,@optname = N'rpc'
    ,@optvalue = N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = N'SSAS'
    ,@optname = N'rpc out'
    ,@optvalue = N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server = N'SSAS'
    ,@optname = N'remote proc transaction promotion'
    ,@optvalue = N'false'
```